# Beautifulsoup improper output while using encoding 'utf-8'

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I was trying to scrape some data off of twitter home page for which I am using beautiful soup. This is my simple code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import requests

r=requests.get('https://twitter.com/')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
print (soup.prettify(encoding='utf-8'))
```

for which I expect an output in a nested form. Instead it just gives me the same garbage like output when I don't use prettify.

Am I missing something. What is causing this. Could some one shed some light on this. I am a beginner and I appreciate any help.

Comment: Try using `lxml` instead of `html`.

Comment: When I run your code I get the output in a nicely nested form.

Comment: @I'L'I I can use lxml, but I was trying to figure out why bs4 was doing this.

Comment: @wilbur I was trying it out on the python compiler and eclipse IDE. both were printing out gibberish. Can you please post a screenshot if possible? Also do you happen to know why this is happening

Comment: I tried in both iPython and the Python interpreter. I don't really know how I would screenshot my output, it's thousands of lines long. Keep in mind that the first few blocks are JavaScript and do look a little funky.

Comment: @wilbur I can't understand why the same code would work for you but not for me.